# I'm getting an error in console Module not found

Tags: css, node.js, reactjs, jsx

```js
import React from 'react'
import './sidebar.css'

import logo from './assets/'
const sidebar = () => {
    return (
        <div className='sideBar grid'>
            <div className='logoDiv flex'>
                <img src='' alt='Image Name'/>
                <h2>xyz</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default sidebar
```

I want to use images from assets but error says module not found

> ERROR in ./src/components/SideBar Section/sidebar.jsx 8:0-32 Module
> not found: Error: Can't resolve '../assets/' in
> 'C:\Users\Sakshi\OneDrive\Desktop\dashboard\src\components\SideBar
> Section'

Comment: You should use code markdown tags.

Comment: Please provide more relevant information, such as your project layout.

Answer (score -2):

```
import React from 'react';
import './sidebar.css';

import logo from './assets/logo.png'; // Replace 'logo.png' with the actual image file name and extension

const Sidebar = () => {
  return (
    // Your JSX code here
  );
};

export default Sidebar;
```

if you are exporting a component try renaming the function as Sidebar with capital S at starting both declaring and exporting. If you are not importing a default function then import it like import {functionName} from "path". Also filename should be starting with capital letter. Name it as Sidebar.jsx. Also check the asset path properly. Because it can not resolve the path.